# circle detection on binary image

Tags: gdal, c++, image, qt

My image is gray scale image which i have converted to binary by smoothing and then edge detection method. Now i want to place the circle /ellipse on edge detected. I don't know how to proceed further. I am using visual C++ and gdal libraries for image processing and Qt for GUI. I should get the output as shown in reference image i have attached.[image]

---

I tried the following code to detect circle. It misses some circle and the size of the circle is same in the image. Please help me out . I am not understanding the argument (specially the threshold). Is canny edge detection is performed internally in houghcircle?

```
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char** argv)
{
   Mat src, src_gray;

   /// Read the image
   src = imread("D:\\hardik\\crater8.tif");
          if( src.empty() )
     { return -1; }

   /// Convert it to gray
    cvtColor( src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

   /// Reduce the noise so we avoid false circle detection
    GaussianBlur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );


    vector<Vec3f> circles;

   /// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
    HoughCircles( src_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,2.0,100.0,128, 64,1, 60 );

   /// Draw the circles detected
    for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
    {
         Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
         int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
         // circle center
         circle( src, center,3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
         // circle outline
         circle( src, center, 30, Scalar(0,255,255),2, 8, 0 );
    }

   /// Show your results
    namedWindow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", src );
//  imwrite("C:\\Test2\\val1.jpg",src);
    waitKey(0);

    src.release();
    src_gray.release();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is answered at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11725/how-to-find-circular-objects-in-an-image. You will find relevant links in related threads at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23560/how-to-detect-crosses-and-circles-in-60x60-raster-images and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23932/looking-for-a-generalised-hough-transform-function-or-a-least-a-function-to-loca.  Could you please explain why this question should appear on a GIS site?

Comment: Have you looked into 2-D Spatial Wavelet Analysis? Wavelets are used in a number of fields (e.g. forestry, astronomy, medical, etc) to automatically detect circular objects from digital images. http://wiki.landscapetoolbox.org/doku.php/remote_sensing_methods:wavelet_analysis

Comment: the link you have provided uses Matlab which already contains predefined functions. I am only using c++. so getting difficulty in finding centroid first as image is in binary form. I have posted this question here because i was unable to post at stackexchange.

Answer (score 2):

You might try looking at OpenCV library. It is better suited for such tasks.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html

Comment: your link gives me some hope to get output in c++. I will try to integrate opencv with vc++ to get the code working. Thank you so much and yes i will get back to you soon if i get stuck in between.